# lxml - using regex in findall() to find tags by attribute values

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to use lxml to get an array of comments that are formatted as

```
<div id="comment-1">
  TEXT
</div>

<div id="comment-2">
  TEXT
</div>

<div id="comment-3">
  TEXT
</div>
...
```

I tried using

```
html.findall(".//div[@id='comment-*']")
```

but this searches for a literal asterisk.

What would be the right syntax for what I'm trying to do?

**EDIT:** I finally got it working by doing

```
doc = lxml.html.parse(url).getroot()
comment_array = doc.xpath('.//div[starts-with(@id, "comment-")]')
```

Comment: try `html.findall(".//div[starts-with(@id,'comment-')")`

Comment: this comment has unmatched brackets - needs a closing `]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular XPath functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib) to find the comments as you suggested:

```
comments = doc.xpath('.//div[starts-with(@id, "comment-")]')
```

But, for more complex matching, you could use **regular expressions**: with lxml, XPath supports regular expressions in the EXSLT namespace. See the official documentation [Regular expressions in XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath).

Here is a demo:

```
from lxml import etree

content = """\
<body>
<div id="comment-1">
  TEXT
</div>

<div id="comment-2">
  TEXT
</div>

<div id="comment-3">
  TEXT
</div>

<div id="note-4">
  not matched
</div>
</body>
"""

doc = etree.XML(content)

# You must give the namespace to use EXSLT RegEx
REGEX_NS = "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"

comments = doc.xpath(r'.//div[re:test(@id, "^comment-\d+$")]',
                          namespaces={'re': REGEX_NS})
```

To see the result, you can "dump" the matched nodes:

```
for comment in comments:
    print("---")
    etree.dump(comment)
```

You get:

```
---
<div id="comment-1">
      TEXT
    </div>


---
<div id="comment-2">
      TEXT
    </div>


---
<div id="comment-3">
      TEXT
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `path` part in [`html.findall`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#findall) only allows an [`XPath subset`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) to be used as expression, it doesn't use regular expressions per default.

To do that you'll have to use the `EXSLT` extension as described [`here`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath) - or you can use the [`xpath core functions`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar desire and did something that while I'm not terribly proud of, got the job done.

```
def node_checker(node):
    if node.attrib['id'].find('hurf-durf') > -1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


for node in itertools.ifilter(node_checker, r.iterdescendants(tag='sometag')):
    print node.tag
```

Not my finest work, but it got me close enough to getElementById with some flexibility that I was able to move on to another problem.